# Web Api 2-Specified cast is not valid

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Whenever I put **case** in my query it gives an error of "Specified cast is not valid" in linq to sql C# but
Its working fine in Sql server 2008.

Below query iam using

```
select Prod_StyleID,S.STYLECODE,STYLENAME,CATEGORYNAME,VENDORNAME,STYLESTATUS,Gendername,
STYLEDESCRIPTION,SHORTDESCRIPTION1,SHORTDESCRIPTION2,SHORTDESCRIPTION3,SHORTDESCRIPTION4,STYLEPRICE,
BRANDNAME,VENDORSTYLECODE,CATEGORYTYPE,1 as ColorATtribute,1 as SizeAttribute,
case when s.styleprice = '0' then sp.regularprice  when s.styleprice = '1' then
sp.saleprice else closeoutprice end as Regularprice from prod_style S inner join prod_styleprice SP on s.stylecode = sp.stylecode where (S.STYLECODE LIKE @stylecode+'%' OR S.VENDORSTYLECODE like @stylecode+'%')
and S.CATEGORYNAME <> 'Made to Order' and S.STYLESTATUS = 'Active' and sp.pricefrom ='1'
```

please help